# How can I access the captcha image that was generated when the page was loaded?

Tags: http, forms, authentication

On some websites, when you want to login, you need to enter a captcha as well. If I want to provide support for an user to enter a captcha into my application ( which will then log into the website ), how would I do this?

My problem is that the link to the captcha image is like this: `example.com/captcha` , and it serves a different image each time it's accesed.

My approach is like this:

- request page
- download image
- show image to user
- user inputs login information
- application logs in

The thing is, if you download the image in order to show it to the user, you're actually receiving a different image than the one generated when the page was loaded, right? How can I get to the image that was generated when the page was loaded, so that when I show it to the user, it's the correct one?

The question is language agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, most captcha will always give you a different image. No way to work around that fact.

The first thing to do, is to open up [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). That way you can see what the browser is doing so that it can autenticate & remain autenticated.

It usually comes down to a cookie being sent. So what you need to do is to hold the cookie on your client app, and have all the requests sent with that cookie. Different platforms provide features to do so, but I'm sure a quick search will show you how.

Remember to pay attention to all being exchanged in fiddler, you need to make sure your apps triggers the same. Besides cookies, pay attention to any hidden field a js might set on the form.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is about sessions, the session your app downloading the image and the session your app submiting the login form may not be the same session, then your captcha will never be correct, you should maitain the session between requests, normally is some cookie set  by the website.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to invent a captcha solution yourself.  Have you considered using [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)?  It's free.

Comment: No. Sorry if I did not express myself correctly. The website I'm trying to log into is not ours. Only the client app is. The captcha image is on server side. I'm only trying to display it on the client GUI app.

Answer (score 1):

Can you be a bit more specific about your situation?  From what you've said, I'm assuming the following:

- You have a "client GUI app" that logs in to a third-party site.  Is this a web-app, or a desktop/standalone application?  In what language is it written?
- Your app contacts the third party site and downloads the Captcha image.  This image is then shown to the user.
- The user enters the captcha phrase and submits it to your app.  Your app then submits this phrase to the site for validation.  This is where sessions come in.  Assuming the remote site uses cookie-based session tracking, you will need to send the same cookie to the third-party server with this submission as you do when the image was downloaded (in the step above).  This allows the server to match your submission to the correct image it sent.  Precisely how you do this depends on what language you've written your app in and the precise structure of it all.  Without more information, a more specific solution is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The image that's generated is also the image served to the user. Your 'main' html page doesn't/shouldn't generate the image, it only embeds it using the image tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a token of some kind with the captcha image, perhaps appended to the filename such as captcha-0ad719bef61bc6a0.jpg and the appended data could link into a temporary table in a database server side that has the correct answer. This would allow you to check things were ok without passing both the image and answer across to your application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I entirely understand this question, but wouldn't you simply store the captcha locally after requesting it from the server, and then embed the local image from the client application, while storing any necessary session captcha data that will allow the captcha to be validated on post, assuming the user input is correct?

If the problem is that the captcha changes everytime you request it, just request it only once.

Can you offer any more clarification if this wouldn't apply to you?

Answer (score 0):

It depends from capcha to another captcha. Maybe you need to use sessions or cookies or some captcha image filename. Show the page with that captcha.